# org.geotools.mbstyle.parse.MBFormatException: "layers" requires JSONArray

Tags: geoserver, geotools

Geoserver 2.14.0 installed on Win7, trying to use mbstyle styling of layers.  Get error "org.geotools.mbstyle.parse.MBFormatException: "layers" requires JSONArray" when using a mbstyle on a layer.

Tried to install java.util.jar in (Program Files)\GeoServer 2.14.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib, no change.

What am I missing?

Log output:
org.geotools.mbstyle.parse.MBFormatException: "layers" requires JSONArray
        at org.geotools.mbstyle.parse.MBObjectParser.getJSONArray(MBObjectParser.java:245)
        at org.geotools.mbstyle.MBStyle.layers(MBStyle.java:135)
        at org.geotools.mbstyle.MBStyle.transform(MBStyle.java:347)
        at org.geotools.mbstyle.MapBoxStyle.parse(MapBoxStyle.java:53)
        at org.geoserver.community.mbstyle.MBStyleHandler.convertToSLD(MBStyleHandler.java:121)
        at org.geoserver.community.mbstyle.MBStyleHandler.parse(MBStyleHandler.java:100)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to provide an **array** in the layers element of your style.

[Such as](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/mbstyle/cookbook/points.html#code):

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "point-circle-test",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "point",
      "type": "circle",
      "paint": {
        "circle-radius": 3,
        "circle-color": "#FF0000",
        "circle-pitch-scale": "map"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```